# Cannot store values of table within instance fields of a custom class

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, class

I have a video class called `VideoClass`.

And I created a method `GetVideoLinkAndDuration()` to retrieve 2 values from videos_tbl from DB & store them in instance fields of `VideoClass`. Just the normal stuff.

**Error**: `Cannot implicitly convert type "project.DataLayer.videos_tbl" to "project.BusinessLayer.VideoClass"`

- I would've solved it with `videos_tbl video = new videos_tbl;` But I need to store db values in custom fields of the custom class as usual (embedURL & vid_duration). **How to do so**?
- Below are the **Class I have**, then the **Method I created which has the error**.

```
    public class VideoClass
    {
        public string embedURL { get; set; }
        public string vid_duration { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public Video GetVideoLinkAndDuration(int videoID)
    {

        testDB db = null;
        int postID = videoID;
        
        VideoClass video = null;

        try
        {
            db = new testDB();
            video = new VideoClass()

            //~~~~ERROR IN BELOW LINE~~~~
            video = db.videos_tbl.Where(x => x.pos_id == postID && x.vid_is_active == true && x.vid_is_deleted == false).FirstOrDefault();
            if (video != null)
            {
                if (video.key != null)
                {
                    video.embedURL = video.resolution240;
                    video.vid_duration = video.resolution360;
                }
                else
                {
                    video.embedURL = Utils.GetResultIfNotNull(video.mp4);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            err.LogErrors(ex.Message, "GetVideoLinkAndDuration", ex.ToString());
        }

        return video;
    }
```

Comment: Your db obviously stores objects of type videos_tbl and not VideoClass. So if you want to get VideoClass objects from this shown method you need a mapping between those to types. From videos_tbl to VideoClass.

Comment: @Ralf please any more details? thanks.

Comment: What details? Your class and the class in the table are two different classes.  If you want to have data living in one sort of class in a different sort of class you have to move/copy/map or whatever you want to call over to the other class. So create a new Videoclass copy over the data from videos_tbl to Videoclass and set all additional things you want to set at Videoclass.